# The difference between 0. and 0

Tags: function-construction, numerics, pattern-matching, downvalues

I have a function for which `0` is a special case:

```
f[A___, 0, B___] := 0
```

But since I am doing numerics, sometimes in the course of things `f` gets called with `0.` instead of `0`. Of course I can add the line

```
f[A___, 0., B___] := 0
```

But I don't understand why I need to because I don't understand the difference between `0` and `0.`. Can anyone illuminate this for me?

(In addition to saving a line of code, or as Jens points out, a couple of characters, I also want to know the difference between them so I don't run into hard-to-debug problems in the future because of something I didn't know about.)

Comment: Mathematica knows the differnece: typing `0.-0` gives the definitive answer: `0.`

Comment: Related: [(5149)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5149)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`0.` is an approximate real number that is very close to zero, while `0` is exactly zero. They aren't the same object, as `0 === 0.` is `False`, and `0.` has a head of `Real`, while `0` has a head of `Integer`.

If you want to turn `0.` into `0`, you can use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html), although that will replace all approximate numbers within some tolerance (by default `10^(-10)`) of zero with `0`.

Comment: +1 - I was writing essentially the same thing while you posted...

Comment: @Jens, @Pillsy, thanks. I arbitrarily choose this as the correct answer. I have chosen to add the line `F[A___, a_?(Equal[#, 0] &), B___]` to be safe: I do not want to cut off at less than 10^-10.

Comment: @Ian I recommend `a_ /; a==0` in place of `a_?(Equal[#, 0] &)` -- it is cleaner, and usually a bit faster.

Comment: We also have 0.0*I which is a complex number that is approximately zero. Also have 0.0''200 which is a real number known to have absolute value less than 10^-200. I find it inconsistent that Head[Re[0.0 I]] is Real, but Head[Re[1.0''200 I ]] is Integer.

Answer (score 20):

To match all sorts of zero, you can use

```
F[A___, zero_ /; zero==0, B___] := 0
```

Another possibility which catches more cases, but also matches some non-zero expressions is to use [`PossibleZeroQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html):

```
F[A___, _?PossibleZeroQ, B___] := 0
```

Comment: [I favor this method as well.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5154/121)  Don't forget the underscore on the LHS though.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Are you aware of any issues with `0|0.`?  (I need to use this right now.)

Comment: @Szabolcs only what I illustrated [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5154/121).  Is there some reason you cannot use `x_ /; x==0`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Performance concerns (it's for a package so it's difficult to assess the performance impact).  Your `MatchQ[0.000000000000000000, 0 | 0.]` example convinced me, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

How about this pattern instead:

```
F[A___, 0 | 0., B___] := 0
```

Now you get zero in both cases.

Regarding the **explanation**: You obviously know that the `0.` comes about when doing numerics, and the reason is that in numerics we're working with approximate real or complex numbers. These are to be distinguished from *exact* numbers of which `0` is an example.

Both are numbers,

```
{NumericQ[0], NumericQ[0.]}
```

> `{True, True}`

but they're different animals as represented by their `Head`:

```
{Head[0], Head[0.]}
```

> `{Integer, Real}`

Therefore, in defining a pattern test, `0` and `0.` show up as non-identical.

Answer (score 13):

I think it is worthwhile to include a table of how different methods compare when deciding about possible zero value. My advice is to use `PossibleZeroQ`, but always make sure to handle/be prepared to all extrema. Let me quote the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html):

> The general problem of determining whether an expression has value
>   zero is undecidable; `PossibleZeroQ` provides a quick but not always
>   accurate test.

```
ClearAll[x];
expr = {0, 0., 0.*10^-1, 1.`1 - 1, 0.0000000000000000000, 
        0 + $MachineEpsilon, 0.0001, 0. I, x};

Panel@TableForm[Transpose@{
     FullForm /@ expr,
     Replace[expr, {0 | 0. -> True, _ -> False}, {1}],
     MatchQ[#, 0 | 0.] & /@ expr, (* same as above *)
     (# === 0 \[Or] # === 0.) & /@ expr ,(* 
     not identical to MatchQ above! *)
     # == 0 & /@ expr,
     (NumericQ@# \[And] # == 0) & /@ expr,
     PossibleZeroQ /@ expr (* same as NumericQ && Equal *)
     }, TableHeadings -> {expr, {FullForm, "rule matching", MatchQ, 
      SameQ, Equal, NumericQ && Equal, PossibleZeroQ}}] /. 
 False -> Item[False, Background -> GrayLevel@.95]
```

[image]

Note that returning `False` for `PossibleZeroQ[x]` is not correct mathematically (e.g. `x` **could be zero**), but sometimes one really only wants to know whether an expression has a numeric value of zero or not (and `x` doesn't have a value).

Please feel free to add further methods/corrections to this table!

Comment: Maybe consider ``1.`1 - 1`` as well...

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, added!

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes I define my pattern using a tolerance value to consider zero:

```
tolerance = 10.^-15;
F[A___, zero_ /; Abs[zero] <= tolerance, B___] := 0;
```

As said before, using `Chop` is possible too (and you can use the second argument to set the tolerance):

```
F[A___, zero_ /; Chop[zero, tolerance]==0, B___] := 0;
```

And if you want to take more cases (like the cases in `PossibleZeroQ`), you can wrap your `zero` by `Simplify`: `Chop[Simplify[zero], tolerance]==0`.