# Mathematica won't simplify multiplication by zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm getting a huge output, but it appears that almost every term should actually be zero, unless I'm misunderstanding the expression.

For example, part of the output reads

> ```
> a (0.25 + 0. b) + b^2 (0. + 0./c) + b (-1. + 0. c) - 0.5 c + (b (-1. b - 0.5 c) c)/a^2
> ```

`Simplify` and `FullSimplify` won't get rid of these zero terms even with assumptions that `a,b` and `c` are real and non-zero.
Suggestions ?

Comment: [`expr /. {x_Real /; x==0 -> 0}`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/the-difference-between-0-and-0)

Comment: Examine the FullForm of the result. You may be surprised. Chop is useful too.

Comment: `SetOptions[Simplify, 
 TransformationFunctions :>  
  Function[x, x //. {0. -> 0, 1. y_ :> y, -1. y_ :> y}]]` and then `Simplify` simplifies as you want.

Comment: @RolfMertig. I think you meant to write `-1. y_ :> -y`

Comment: @RunnyKine : sure. thanx.

Answer (score 4):

To get what was said in the comments on record as an answer.

`Chop` is probably what you are looking for.

```
expr = 
  a (0.25 + 0. b) + b^2 (0. + 0./c) + b (-1. + 0. c) - 0.5 c + 
   (b (-1. b - 0.5 c) c)/a^2 // Chop
```

> ```
> 0.25 a - 1. b - 0.5 c + (b (-1. b - 0.5 c) c)/a^2
> ```

You might want to go further

```
expr = expr /. {1. x_ :> x, -1. x_ :> -x}
```

> ```
> 0.25 a - b - 0.5 c + (b (- b - 0.5 c) c)/a^2
> ```

#### Update

In general expressions with inexact coefficients can contain the forms `0.x`, `1.x`, and `-1.x`. None of these cause computation difficulties, but they are unattractive, and often we want to eliminate them.

With a help from Mr.Wizard, I offer the following pattern to do this task.

```
fixerPattern = u_ /; Sign[u] == u :> Sign[u]
```

With this we can clean up

```
expr = 
  a (0.25 + 0. b) + b^2 (0. + 0./c) + 1.b (-1. + 0. c) - 0.5 c + 
    (b (-1. b - 0.5 c) c)/a^2
```

without using `Chop` and it takes care of the instances of both `1.b` and `-1.b`.

```
expr /. fixerPattern
```

[image: fixup]

Comment: I think you'll want something like `/. {c_ x_ /; c == 1 :> x, c_ x_ /; c == -1 :> -x}` for generality?  (As you used in a more recent answer...)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. What do you think of `/. c_ x_ /; Abs[c ] == 1 :> Sign[c] x` as a more concise alternative?

Comment: Might not that affect complex values in a strange way?  A contrived example: ``(0.5` + 0.8660254037844386` I) /. c_ /; Abs[c] == 1 :> foo``

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Good point, What about this? `/. c_Real x_ /; Abs[c] == 1 :> Sign[c] x`

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I believe we could handle all three cases (including zero) with one rule: `x_ /; Sign[x] == x :> Sign[x]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Looks really good!

Comment: Wouldn't Rationalize[expr,0] work ?

Comment: @Lotus. That might have undesirable side effects on computations with `expr` that follow because it affects all the inexact quantities.