# Simplifying expressions containing unit of zero magnitude

Tags: simplifying-expressions, units

I have obtained the following form as a part of a computation:

```
k (Quantity[0, "Kilohertz"]) + Quantity[1/500, "Kilohertz"]
```

This is typeset as

[image]

Here, `k` is an atom (representing an integer in my computation).  Obviously I would like this to simplify to `Quantity[2, "Hertz"]`, but I cannot figure out how to cause the term with `k` to vanish.  Neither `FullSimplify` nor `UnitSimplify` have any effect here:

[image]

My best guess is that *Mathematica* doesn't want to assume things about `k`, but given that the magnitude of the unit is `0`, it should still simplify away.

How can I simplify this as I would expect?

Comment: try `Simplify[....,Assumptions->Element[k,Reals]]`

Comment: @george2079 no dice.  Same effect as without the `Assumptions` -- the form is untouched.

Comment: Related: [(34967)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34967/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Unprotect[Quantity]
Quantity /: Times[Quantity[mag_, unit_], seq__] := 
Quantity[Times[mag, seq], unit]
```

This will leads to your desired result, and also works for symbolic `Times` in `Quantity`

Comment: That's a good idea.  Is it wise to edit builtin rules like Quantity?  Also, would `Quantity[0, __] := 0` be a better rule or worse?  (I don't know general conventions, thanks.)

Comment: @thirtythreeforty your idea also "edits" the built-in function (requires `Unprotect[ Quantity]`) . Which to do depends on your need.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved it by simply using a replacement rule.

```
k (Quantity[0, "Kilohertz"]) + Quantity[1/500, "Kilohertz"]

UnitConvert[Out[1] /. Quantity[0, "Kilohertz"] -> 0, "Hertz"]
```

Here's what it looks like in a notebook:

[image]

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Louis, thanks for the formatting suggestion.